Javascript .map() an object of arrays
I'm trying to .map() an object of arrays to create a div for each key/value pair. Here is a sample of the object format:
const data = {
   year: ["2018", "2020"],
   make: ["Honda"],
   model: ["Accord", "Civic"],
   subModel: []
}

Here is what I have:
const filterChips = Object.entries(data)
        .flatMap(([key, value]) => [value].flat()
            .filter(v => v !== "" && v !== null)
            .map(v => [key, v]))
        .map(it => (<div>{it}</div>));

Which gives me the output:
<div>year2018</div>
<div>year2020</div>
<div>makeHonda</div>
<div>modelAccord</div>
<div>modelCivic</div>

Which is almost what I want, but I would like to be able to separate the key/value in each div so last line of code is:
.map(it => (<div>{it.key}: {it.value}</div>));

So that the output would be:
<div>year: 2018</div>
<div>year: 2020</div>
<div>make: Honda</div>
<div>model: Accord</div>
<div>model: Civic</div>

I feel like I'm close, but tuck on the last part...

Try replacing  it.key and it.value with  it[0] and it[1].

Too many loop, just use forEach and for .. in. let filterChipsa = []; for (let k in data) {   if (data[k].length < 1) continue;   data[k].forEach(v => {     if (v === "" || v === null) return;     filterChipsa.push(<div>{k}: {v}</div>);   }) }

Thanks @James, that worked perfectly!

You can use an inner .map() on your inner vals arrays to map htem divs, and then return these array of divs from your .flatMap() to merge all them together into one array. There is no need to create a wrapper array [value] and call .flat() on that:
const filterChips = Object.entries(data).flatMap(([key, vals]) => 
  vals.map(val => <div>{key}: {val}</div>)
);

To incorporate a filter, you can filter out before you .map():
vals.filter(val => val !== "" && val !== null).map(val => <div>{key}: {val}</div>)

Runnable Example:


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.25.6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
const data = {
   year: ["2018", "2020"],
   make: ["Honda"],
   model: ["Accord", "Civic"],
   subModel: []
};

const filterChips = Object.entries(data).flatMap(([key, vals]) => 
  vals.map(val => <div>{key}: {val}</div>
));

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body).render(<React.Fragment>{filterChips}</React.Fragment>);
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
}, 0);
</script>




I'm not sure why your snippet isn't runnable, the run button appears while editing. Try unchecking the "Hide snippet" option.

@Barmar Thanks, yeah I was confused about that, I'll give that a go

@Barmar I think it's because I tried clicking the "Use Babel TS Presets" checkbox (I hadn't seen it before). Seems to break the snippet if you check it / uncheck it.

It's still not runnable

@Barmar Interesting, if I remove the new snippet header that it's adding and use the old one, it's "runnable", but the code crashes. All my previous React snippets on old answers are now crashing...

You can map the Object.keys instead and filter out empty values.
const filterChips = Object.keys(data).map((key) => (
    data[key] != "" ? `<div>${key}: ${data[key]}</div>` : false
)).filter((item) => item);

Hope that helps.

reducers give you a lot more flexibility.
const filterChips  = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, value])=>{
  for(const v of value){
    acc.push((<div>{key}: {v}</div>))
  }
return acc
}, [])

And golfed into one line so it can be "pretty"
const filterChips = Object.entries(data).reduce((a,[k,v])=>a.concat(v.map(x=>`<div>${k}: ${x}</div>`)),[]);


Mixing reduce with a loop is really ugly. Either use array methods, or just two loops.

...Interesting opinion...
